# How to replace and format a date in a string with sed and date command?

Tags: linux, bash, date, sed

I have a string like `"M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;010622;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX"`, where the seventh field is a date with ddmmyy format. I need to replace this field with a date in the same format, but 3 days earlier.

I tried the following:

```
echo "M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;010622;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX" | sed "s/;\([0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]2[0-9]\);/;$(date -d "$(date -d \1 '+%d%m%y') - 3 days" '+%d%m%y');/"
```

The problem is, that i can use a reference (\1) or a script ($(date ..)), but i can't create a working example where both are working. I think it is a problem with quotes, but i'm also unable to escape them properly. Also switches for sed like `-E, -e, -r` won't help me either. I'd like to see a working sed example, but i'm also thinking to solve this with awk.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A shorter example of this failing: `$ echo "before;010622;after" | sed "s/;\([0-3][0-9][0-1][0-9]2[0-9]\);/;$(date -d \1);/"` replaces with today's date, instead of 010622.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` would probably be a better candidate but as you ask for a `sed` solution...

With GNU `sed` you can execute the result of a successful substitution with the shell and replace the pattern space with the result, thanks to the `e` flag of the substitute command. Example with the `date` utility from GNU `coreutils` **if your line does not contain `date` formatting controls and no quotes**:

```
$ printf 'M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;010622;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX' |
sed -E 's/(([^;]*;){6})(..)(..)(..)(.*)/date -d "\5\4\3 -3 days" +"\1%d%m%y\6"/e'
M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;290522;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX
```

This substitutes the input line with the `date` command that produces your expected output. With your example:

```
date -d "220601 -3 days" +"M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;%d%m%y;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX"
```

Note the reordering from day-month-year to year-month-day. It is then executed by the shell thanks to the `e` flag.

If the rest of the line could be interpreted as formatting commands by `date` we need something a bit more complex:

```
$ printf 'M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;010622;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX' |
sed -E 'h
s/([^;]*;){6}(..)(..)(..).*/date -d "\4\3\2 -3 days" +%d%m%y/e
G;s/(.*)\n(([^;]*;){6}).{6}(.*)/\2\1\4/'
M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;290522;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX
```

- Copy the pattern space containing the input line to the hold space (`h`).
- Substitute the full line with `date -d "yymmdd -3 days" +%d%m%y` where `yymmdd` is the date in year-month-day format (`220601` in your example). The result is executed by the shell and the pattern space is replaced with the result thanks to the `e` flag. In your example it now contains `290522`.
- Append a newline and the hold space to the pattern space (`G`). At this point the pattern space contains (with your example):

  ```
  290522\nM;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;010622;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX
  ```
- Finally substitute the pattern space with the final format you want.

Answer (score 3):

With awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
 FS = OFS = ";"
}
{
  dt = substr($7, 5, 2) substr($7, 3, 2) substr($7, 1, 2)
  cmd = "date -d \"" dt "-3days\" +%d%m%y"
  cmd | getline $7
  close(cmd)
  print
}'
```

This can be a lot faster with GNU awk of course.

```
gawk '
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ";"
  cmd = "stdbuf -oL date -f - +%d%m%y"
}
{
  dt = substr($7, 5, 2) substr($7, 3, 2) substr($7, 1, 2)
  print dt "-3days" |& cmd
  cmd |& getline $7
  print
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I find [`dateutils`](https://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) is often more convenient for date/time manipulation, e.g. with `paste` and `cut` from coreutils (assuming data comes from `infile`):

```
paste -d';'                                                                 \
      <( <infile cut -d';' -f1-6 )                                          \
      <( <infile cut -d';' -f7 | dateadd -i '%d%m%y' -f '%d%m%y' -- '-3d' ) \
      <( <infile cut -d';' -f8- )
```

Answer (score 2):

With the shell and date: date needs the input date format to be `mm/dd/yy` so a little string manipulation is required.

```bash
s="M;12345678900000;Z;;FEWO;F;010622;0.0;;;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;;;XXX"
# split the string
IFS=';' read -ra fields <<<"$s"
# reset the date
fields[5]=$(date -d "${fields[5]:2:2}/${fields[5]:0:2}/${fields[5]:4} - 3 days" '+%d%m%y')
# and join the fields
t=$(IFS=';'; echo "${fields[*]}")
echo "$t"
```

```
M;12345678900000;Z;FEWO;F;290522;0.0;1.00;0.00;1.25;Y;XXX=tp
                          ^^^^^^
```